# Looping through dataframe not binding to original dataframe

Tags: r

I wrote a function to loop through a dataframe, change the data and cbind the transformed vector onto the original dataframe. But the cbinding does not seem to be working:

```
numeric_vars <- data[c("tenure", "MonthlyCharges", "TotalCharges")]

> str(numeric_vars)
'data.frame':   7043 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ tenure        : int  1 34 2 45 2 8 22 10 28 62 ...
 $ MonthlyCharges: num  29.9 57 53.9 42.3 70.7 ...
 $ TotalCharges  : num  29.9 1889.5 108.2 1840.8 151.7 ...

# write a function to categorize numeric_vars
categorizeNums <- function(vect){
  as_category <- cut(vect, breaks=(quantile(vect, probs=seq(0,1, by=0.25),include.lowest=TRUE, na.rm=TRUE)))
  numeric_vars <- cbind(numeric_vars, as_category)
}

for ( i in numeric_vars ) {
  categorizeNums(i)
}

# I expected numeric_vars data frame to have 3 new variables but...
> str(numeric_vars)
'data.frame':   7043 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ tenure        : int  1 34 2 45 2 8 22 10 28 62 ...
 $ MonthlyCharges: num  29.9 57 53.9 42.3 70.7 ...
 $ TotalCharges  : num  29.9 1889.5 108.2 1840.8 151.7 ...
```

I tested the function on the variables within numeric_vars individually and it works as expected:

```
> test_tenure <- cut(numeric_vars$tenure, breaks=(quantile(numeric_vars$tenure, probs=seq(0,1, by=0.25),include.lowest=TRUE, na.rm=TRUE)))
> str(test_tenure)
 Factor w/ 4 levels "(0,9]","(9,29]",..: 1 3 1 3 1 1 2 2 2 4 ...
> test_MonthlyCharges <- cut(numeric_vars$MonthlyCharges, breaks=(quantile(numeric_vars$MonthlyCharges, probs=seq(0,1, by=0.25),include.lowest=TRUE, na.rm=TRUE)))
> str(test_MonthlyCharges)
 Factor w/ 4 levels "(18.2,35.5]",..: 1 2 2 2 3 4 3 1 4 2 ...
> test_TotalCharges <- cut(numeric_vars$TotalCharges, breaks=(quantile(numeric_vars$TotalCharges, probs=seq(0,1, by=0.25),include.lowest=TRUE, na.rm=TRUE)))
> str(test_TotalCharges)
 Factor w/ 4 levels "(18.8,401]","(401,1.4e+03]",..: 1 3 1 3 1 2 3 1 3 3 ...
```

After I call `categorizeNums(i)`, why are the new columns not being binded with `numeric_vars <- cbind(numeric_vars, as_category)`?

Comment: Read about environments and functions.

Comment: @Carl why bother commenting

Comment: You're binding things within a function and expecting them to exist outside the function unless I'm reading something incorrectly

Comment: @Carl I'm binding a vector created within the function to a data frame that exists already outside of the function. This is how it's done no? It's how it's done in JS and surely reasonable to try it this way with R? If not then how does one bind the post looped data to a variable for future use?

Comment: Your function returns nothing since there is no object numeric vars to bind with

Comment: Try making the last line of the function just `cbind(numeric_vars, as_category)`.  Functions should always return a value.  Then what does `lapply(numeric_vars, categorizeNums)` give?  Some example data would be helpful too.

Comment: @RichardScriven this provides me with a list of 3 dataframes, each with the original 3 vars + the respective "as_category" var. It's a step closer for sure. Why can't I bind to an existing data frame that lives outside of the function? Or can I and am I just missing something?

Comment: You can, but it's dangerous.  Okay, so remove the entire final line of `categorizeNums()` and make it `as_category`.  So then `lapply()` should give you the three columns for replacement.

Comment: all you to do is change the line `numeric_vars <<- cbind(numeric_vars, as_category)` in your function.  But, this is bad practce in R.  It is rare for functions to take arguments by reference (allowing you to modify the variable outside the scope of the function) in R..Look at `data.table` package if this is what are after,

Comment: Thanks @RichardScriven that did the trick

Comment: @bunk good to know. This is different to what I'm used to